# Redirect to Login Page if Session expired in ASP MVC net core

Tags: session, .net-core, asp.net-mvc-5, actionfilterattribute

I am working in ASP net core MVC Application. My aim is to redirect to the login page if the session expired.
In my case, I am using several ajax call to load a page. Sometimes it is redirecting properly, but sometimes it is not doing so.

```
 public class CheckSessionIsAvailable : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);

        if (filterContext.HttpContext == null || filterContext.HttpContext.Session.GetString("UserID") == null)
        {
            //return RedirectToAction("Index", "Login");

            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new
            {
                controller = "Login",
                action = "Index"
            }));
        }
    }
}
```

Created an action filter **CheckSessionIsAvailable** and associated it with all the controllers.

```
[CheckSessionIsAvailable]
public class TestController : Controller
{

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Am I doing anything wrong while creating **Action Filter** ?

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this by using the `OnActionExecuting` method of `IActionFilter` by redefining it in our custom class.

First add it to the services:

```
services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
{
    options.Filters.Add(typeof(RequestAuthenticationFilter));
});
```

Then create a custom class `RequestAuthenticationFilter` and define the `OnActionExecuting` method.

```
public class RequestAuthenticationFilter : IActionFilter
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _httpContextAccessor;
    public RequestAuthenticationFilter(IHttpContextAccessor httpContextAccessor)
    {
        _httpContextAccessor = httpContextAccessor;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// OnActionExecuting
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context"></param>
    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        var session = _httpContextAccessor.HttpContext.Session.Get("UserId");
        if (session == null)
        {
            context.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new { action = "Login", controller = "Account", area = "Identity" }));
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// OnActionExecuted
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context"></param>
    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: How to pass theIHttpContextAccessor class object from the controller to actionfilter, while applying it to the entire controller?  Could you please show the controller part as well.

Comment: One you register the filter in services you don’t need to apply to every controller explicitly. 

services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
{
options.Filters.Add(typeof(RequestAuthenticationFilter));
});

Comment: I also need to redirect back to the login page when the session expires and this seems to work except when the page is first loaded.  Since the Session has not yet been created, the MVC app gets stuck in an infinite loop.  How do  we tell it to not do a redirect on the "First Load"?