# In .NET Core 6, if the user session has expired then needs to redirect/route to the login action method from any controller action method

Tags: .net-core, .net-6.0

I am new to .NET Core 6, I am trying to manage the session state, if the user session has expired then need to redirect/route to the login action method from any controller action method. I want to redirect/route from a single point.

Comment: If you've configured your app correctly, the redirecting should be done for you automatically.   What authentication method are you using?   Identity cookies?

Comment: I have populated all the menus dynamically from the database by using the raw query. Also, using all raw queries for fetching data and checking the user. After getting user info store it in session. I don't use framework methods like Identity. So my goal is simple if the session expires then route to the login page from a single point for every action method but cannot able to do that. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62155214/redirect-to-login-page-if-session-expired-in-asp-mvc-net-core?rq=2

Comment: No, this option needs to assign every action method but I want to redirect/route from a single point. Also, note that now I am able to implement IRouter in my class but not able to get session data using HttpContext.Session.GetString("UserData") in that class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My goal was to populate menus dynamically from the database using raw query and if the user session has expired then needs to redirect/route to the login action method from any controller action method.

I read many articles and was able to resolve it. I don't know if it is standard or not.

I used the controller-based custom attribute for authentication and authorization.

For session management need to add the following service before "var app = builder.Build();"

```
builder.Services.AddSession(options =>
{
    options.IdleTimeout= TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
});
```

and after "var app = builder.Build();" need to add "app.UseSession()";

To set the session value and get the session value I have created a class SessionManager.

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace SessionAndRouting.Helper
{
    public static class SessionManager
    {
        public static void SetObjectAsJson(this ISession session, string key, object value)
        {
            session.SetString(key, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value));
        }

        public static T GetObjectFromSession<T>(this ISession session, string key)
        {
            var value = session.GetString(key);
            return value == null ? default(T) : JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(value);
        }
    }
}
```

In my Login action method set the session value for the user and menu like below.

```
 public IActionResult Login()
        {
            HttpContext.Session.SetString("UserData", "5");

            List<Menu> menulist = new List<Menu>();
            menulist.Add(new Menu { Id = 1, ActionName ="Index" });
            menulist.Add(new Menu { Id = 2, ActionName ="Login" });    
           
            //HttpContext.Session.SetString("MenuList", menulistJson);    
            SessionManager.SetObjectAsJson(HttpContext.Session,"MenuList2",menulist);

            return View();
        }
```

The controller-based custom attribute for authentication and authorization.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters;
using SessionAndRouting.Models;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace SessionAndRouting.Helper
{
    public sealed class UserPermissionAttribute : Attribute, IAuthorizationFilter
    {

        public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
        {
            if (context != null)
            {
                var descriptor = context?.ActionDescriptor as ControllerActionDescriptor;
                var ctrorlerlName = descriptor.ControllerName;
                var actionName = descriptor.ActionName.ToLower();

                if (actionName != "login")
                {
                    var session = context.HttpContext.Session.GetString("UserData");


                    if (session != null)
                    {
                        List<Menu> menuList = new List<Menu>();
                        List<Menu> menuList2 = new List<Menu>();
                        menuList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Menu>>(context.HttpContext.Session.GetString("MenuList"));
                        menuList2 = SessionManager.GetObjectFromSession<List<Menu>>(context.HttpContext.Session, "MenuList2");
                        if (menuList2.Count > 0)
                        {
                           foreach (var menu in menuList2)
                            {
                                if (menu.ActionName.ToLower() == actionName)
                                {
                                    return;
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    context.Result = new RedirectResult("/Home/Login");
                                }
                            }                            
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            context.Result = new RedirectResult("/Home/Login");
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        context.Result = new RedirectResult("/Home/Login");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Assign the custom attribute above the controller like as

```
[UserPermissionAttribute].
public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
```